# Issue Creating LP Pair With IUniswapV2Router & IUniswapV2Factory

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, ethers.js

I am unsuccessful trying to create an LP pair with `IUniswapV2Factory` and adding tokens to with `IUniswapV2Router`'s `addLiquidityETH` or `addLiquidity` programmatically (via ethersjs).

I have ensured that both the tokens I am trying to add have approval allowances. But continually getting the error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
```

Below is my ethersjs code I am using:

```
    // APPROVE A TOKENS
    const txA = await aContract.approve(deployer.address, BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A0000"));
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + txA.hash);
    await txA.wait();

    // APPROVE B TOKEN
    const tx1 = await bContract.approve(deployer.address, BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A000"));
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + tx1.hash);
    await tx1.wait();

    // CREATE SPOOKY LP PAIR
    const tx = await spookyFactoryContract.createPair(
      aContract.address,
      bContract.address,
    );
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + tx.hash);
    await tx.wait();

    // GET SPOOKY LP PAIR
    const pair = await spookyFactoryContract.getPair(
      aContract.address,
      bContract.address,
    );
    console.log("a/b " + pair);
```

Then upon trying to add liquidity with:

```
    // ADD A AND B TOKENS TO SPOOKY LP PAIR
    const tx1 = await spookyRouterContract.addLiquidity(
      aContract.address,
      bContract.address,
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      deployer.address,
      BigNumber.from("0x621df7f5000"),
    );
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + tx1.hash);
    await tx1.wait();
```

I get the error mentioned above:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
```

I know that the creating LP pair isn't necessary as it is internal to the [UniswapRouterV2](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xf491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c29#code)'s `addLiquidity` but just for completeness I am showing it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! These solutions [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/111624/93211), [2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/107504/93211), [3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/86931/93211) were super helpful for me to piece it together...

I needed to either:
A) include the `{value: 125}` param to the `addLiquidityEth` for the transfer of the LP to my address
*or*
B) I could have approved the spending on the pair's contract then used `addLiquidity`. This would be necessary if pairing with none native (i.e. weth on ethereum or wftm or fantom) tokens I believe.

Solution A):

```
    // ADD A TOKENS TO SPOOKY LP PAIR
    console.log("spookyRouter: addLiquidityETH");
    const tx1 = await spookyRouterContract.addLiquidityETH(
      aContract.addr,
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A000"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D7A000"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D7A000"),
      deployer.address,
      BigNumber.from("0x621df7f5000"),
      {value : 125}
    );
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + tx1.hash);
    await tx1.wait();
```

Solution B):

```
    // APPROVE THE LP PAIR
    console.log("uniswapPair: approve");
    const txAlp = await spookyPairContract.approve(deployer.address, BigNumber.from("0x2B5E3AF16B188000"));
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + txAlp.hash);
    await txAlp.wait();

    // ADD VINYL TOKENS TO SPOOKY LP PAIR
    console.log("spookyRouter: addLiquidity");
    const tx2 = await spookyRouterContract.addLiquidity(
      contractInfo.tomb.addr,
      wftmAddress,
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      BigNumber.from("0x16345785D8A00"),
      deployer.address,
      BigNumber.from("0x621df7f5000"),
    );
    console.log("https://ftmscan.com/tx/" + tx2.hash);
    await tx2.wait();
```